# Using a variable from an API in scss

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass

I have a path that is already stored on an api. So when I call it in typescript, I'd just type like `${var.image}/asset/image/image.png`. But what if I use this variable in my scss? The only thing I could do is to declare `$imageUrl: '../asset/image'`, and use it as follows:

```
//This is main.scss
$imagesUrl: '../assets/images';
.this_container {
   background: url(#{imagesUrl}/image.png)
}
```

```
//This is the mainPage.tsx
import * as React from 'react';
import './style/main.scss'

class Component extends React.Component<any, any> {
  render(){
    return(
      <div className='this_container'>
        <h1>This is the Container</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Component
```

any ideas how can set `$var.imagesUrl` because this is giving an error in scss.

Comment: could you post the involved files?

Comment: There are two involved files. I have a mainPage.tsx where I import the main.scss file.

Comment: Great. you should post them both so people can help you and be able to see the full picture

Comment: @Juan. I think you should take a look

Comment: I don't think this is possible with scss. SCSS files are compiled to css and any API call will definitely happen at javascript side.

Answer (score -1):

you are missing a $. You should do

```
$imagesUrl: '../assets/images';
.this_container {
   background: url(#{$imageUrl}/image.png) 
}
```

Comment: You're missing my question. Supposedly, I have a variable from the api. I need to call declare ```#{$var.imagesUrl}``` instead of ```#{$imageUrl}```

Comment: hey,  there's no need for a downvote. You posted your problem without providing any code or explanation at first. I just gave the reasonable answer with the super limited information your provided . With the new information I can tell you that what you are asking is not possible, you may have to do some conditional rerendering. Read the guidelines to create better posts, and I would ask you to remove the downvote if possible since I was trying to help you with almost no information from your side.